# I need help making my first Android app...I have some issues

Tags: android, text-editor

Need help with this code. When I click Settings item in the menu, it crashes. I have looked in the MainActivity.java file and I can't find the source of the problem. What can I do?? I am a beginner and I really want to make this work. If anyone can help that would be amazing.

```
package natanrosenfeld.texteditor;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.content.Intent;
import com.natanrosenfeld.texteditor.R;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.view.Gravity;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);




}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem action_settings) {
        Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),SettingsActivity.class);
        startActivity(i);
    int id = action_settings.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(action_settings);


}
```

}

Comment: Do you create SettingActivity? Did you register it in Manifest?

Comment: Post your log from Log cat

Comment: I did create SettingsActivity in the AndroidManifest.

Comment: If you want us to help we need the entire code and the error in the log cat. Add manifest also/

Comment: How do I post the Manifest?

Comment: You need a `setContentView(R.layout.some_layout_here);`, in your `onCreate()`.

Comment: Copy file and paste it on your post

Answer (score 0):

Write the Intent inside if condition. Are you trying to display Settings activity after selecting Settings button? if yes then make the following change:

```
if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),SettingsActivity.class);
        startActivity(i);
return true;
    }
```

Make sure you have Settings activity declared in manifest file. Hope this may help you.

Comment: Yes you need setContentView in onCreate method like:

setContentView(R.layout.your_layout_name);

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. Seems that I was using two layouts instead of one, for one page! Thank you for your help!